# Can you change the process template, when you branch a project?

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

When branching a TFS team project, can you change the process template used by the new branch, to something else? For example, if the project template used for the original project was CMMI, when I branch the TFS team project, can I then make the new TFS team project use the Scrum process template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "branch" a team project. You can create an inherited process template.

However, you can't change an existing team project between the root-level process templates (Scrum, Agile, and CMMI).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if based on this document: [Change the process used by a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#change-the-process-used-by-a-project):

> You can change the process a project uses from a system process or
>   inherited process to an inherited process. You can only change
>   projects to use another process that inherits from the same system
>   process. That is, you can change an Agile-based project to any process
>   you created from the Agile system process as well as to the Agile
>   process.

However, if your branch project contains some custom data from your custom template it will be a problem. In my case, I`ve created a new work item type in the inherited process. I have created a new project from this inherited process. I have created a new work item for the custom work item type. The change process wizard selects this process but nothing happens. 
I have deleted this custom work item and the wizard moves the new project to the root process.